# Looping through an array, displaying elements that match a criteria

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have this big array that I need to break down and only display specific elements within it that match a criteria.

My array looks like this.

```
[
  {
                 :id => 9789,
               :name => "amazing location",
           :priority => 1,
         :address_id => 12697,
           :disabled => false
  },
  {
                 :id => 9790,
               :name => "better location",
           :priority => 1,
         :address_id => 12698,
           :disabled => false
  },
  {
                 :id => 9791,
               :name => "ok location",
           :priority => 1,
         :address_id => 12699,
           :disabled => true
  }
]
```

What I need is to only display the elements within this array that have `disabled` set to `true`.

However when I try this, I get the error stating `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

```
array.map do |settings, value|
  p hash[:disabled][:true]   
end
```

I'm wondering if there is another way, or if there is a way to do this. If anyone could take a look, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this with a short `each` or `select`.

```
a.each { |k,_v| puts k if k[:disabled] == true }
=> {:id=>9791, :name=>"ok location", :priority=>1, :address_id=>12699, :disabled=>true}
```

This iterates over each element (`hash`) inside the array you have and checks if the value of the key disabled on each value is true, and puts the key, just for example, you can set it as you want to do.

Or shorter:

```
puts a.select { |k,_v| k[:disabled] }
=> {:id=>9791, :name=>"ok location", :priority=>1, :address_id=>12699, :disabled=>true}
```

Comment: If you're just doing `puts` inside the block, there's no really point to use `select` in the first example. `each` would do just fine

Comment: So I was looking into select, however within my rails project, if I try using that I wind up getting a `NoMethodError: private method `select' called for nil:NilClass`  I'm not sure what the best way around that is right now.

Comment: @kdweber89 I think I'd need more info, or the code to see where's the problem.

Comment: I got it working, turns out I was using it in the wrong spot. Thanks so much for looking into this @SebastiánPalma

Answer (score 3):

By providing two arguments to `#map` on an array, you're actually getting the first hash and then nil.  When in reality you just want to loop for each and select those where disabled is true.  You can do that instead with [`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-select) which will filter all elements of the array where the block returns a truthy value:

```
print array.select { |hash| hash[:disabled] }
=> [{:id=>9791, :name=>"ok location", :priority=>1, :address_id=>12699, :disabled=>true}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error shows up when you are treating an array or string as a Hash.

In PHP, array keys can be either numbers or strings, whereas in Ruby associative arrays are a separate data type, called a hash.

Here’s a cheatsheet for various foreach variants, translated into idiomatic Ruby:

**Looping over a numeric array (PHP) :**

```
<?php

$items = array( 'orange', 'pear', 'banana' );

# without indexes
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    echo $item;
}

# with indexes
foreach ( $items as $i => $item ) {
    echo $i, $item;
}
```

**Looping over an array (Ruby) :**

```
items = ['orange', 'pear', 'banana']

# without indexes
items.each do |item|
    puts item
end

# with indexes
items.each_with_index do |item, i|
    puts i, item
end
```

**Looping over an associative array (PHP) :**

```
<?php

$continents = array(
    'africa' => 'Africa',
    'europe' => 'Europe',
    'north-america' => 'North America'
);

# without keys
foreach ( $continents as $continent ) {
    echo $continent;
}

# with keys
foreach ( $continents as $slug => $title ) {
    echo $slug, $title;
}
```

**Looping over a hash (Ruby):**

```
continents = {
    'africa' => 'Africa',
    'europe' => 'Europe',
    'north-america' => 'North America'
}

# without keys
continents.each_value do |continent|
    puts continent
end

# with keys
continents.each do |slug, title|
    puts slug, title
end
```

In Ruby 1.9 hashes were improved so that they preserved their internal order. In Ruby 1.8, the order in which you inserted items into a hash would have no correlation to the order in which they were stored, and when you iterated over a hash, the results could appear totally random. Now hashes preserve the order of insertion, which is clearly useful when you are using them for keyword arguments in method definitions. (thanks  steenslag for correcting me on this)

Comment: "elements inside a Ruby hash are not ordered" Hashes preserve their insertion order since Ruby 1.9.0 (2007).